# Problem locating 'cmap' subtables in TrueType file (C#)

Tags: c#, truetype, opentype

I am writing a TrueType reader, mostly as an exercise to improve my understanding of both TrueType/OpenType and C#, but I have gotten stuck reading the tables, specifically the 'cmap' table (the first one I'm trying).

I have been able to read the start of the file, finding the header that details the tables in the file, and then I have started reading the 'cmap' table, and this is where my problem is. I can read the encoding record headings, getting their platform ids, encoding ids and offsets, but when I attempt to move to the table itself, I arrive at the wrong place, getting results like: `Format: 18244, Length: 17734, Language: 1822` which seems very clearly wrong.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is with myself having the wrong start position where I am applying the offset from, but from I can't manage to learn any more from my reading of the Microsoft OpenType documentation.

```
internal class EncodingTable
    {
        public ushort Format { get; }
        public ushort Length { get; }
        public ushort Language { get; }
        public byte[] GlyphIdArray { get; }

        public EncodingTable(ushort format, ushort length, ushort language, byte[] glyphIdArrays)
        {
            Format = format;
            Length = length;
            Language = language;
            GlyphIdArray = glyphIdArrays;
        }
    }

internal class EncodingRecord
    {
        public ushort PlatformId { get; }
        public ushort EncodingId { get; }
        public uint Offset { get; }
        public EncodingTable Table; 

        public EncodingRecord(ushort platformId, ushort encodingId, uint recordOffset, BinaryReader reader, long tableStart)
        {
            PlatformId = platformId;
            EncodingId = encodingId;
            Offset = recordOffset;
            _reader = reader;

            Console.WriteLine("Platform: {0}, Encoding: {1}, Offset: {2}", PlatformId, EncodingId, Offset);

            long start = reader.BaseStream.Position;

            reader.BaseStream.Position = tableStart;
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(Offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ushort format = reader.ReadUInt16();
            ushort length = reader.ReadUInt16();
            ushort language = reader.ReadUInt16();
            Console.WriteLine("Format: {0}, Length: {1}, Language: {2}", format, length, language);

            reader.BaseStream.Position = start;
        }
    }

internal class CmapTable : FontDataTable
    {
        public ushort Version { get; }
        public ushort NumTables { get; }
        public List<EncodingRecord> EncodingRecords { get; } = new List<EncodingRecord>();

        public CmapTable(string tag, uint checksum, uint offset, uint length, BinaryReader reader, string name) 
            : base(tag, checksum, offset, length, reader, name)
        {
            long start = reader.BaseStream.Position;

            _reader.BaseStream.Seek(_offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Version = reader.ReadUInt16();
            NumTables = reader.ReadUInt16();
            long pos = reader.BaseStream.Position;
            long tableStart = pos + (NumTables * 8);
            for (int i = 0; i < NumTables; i++)
            {
                EncodingRecords.Add(new EncodingRecord(reader.ReadUInt16(), reader.ReadUInt16(), reader.ReadUInt32(), reader, tableStart));
            }
            reader.BaseStream.Position = start;
        }
    }
```

'FontDataTable' is simply a base class for all the tables I will be reading, holding the common fields (such as _reader), and allowing an easy way to store them all in a collection. My general coding probably isn't great, and I'm certain it isn't the most efficient, but hopefully that'll improve as I learn more.

Comment: I assume you mean OpenType reader, because there is no such thing as a TrueType font, that's just a colloquialism. There are only OpenType fonts, some of which use the TrueType vector language for their glyph outlines, and thus (for historical reasons) have `ttf` as extension =) With that said, you'll want to fix `reader.BaseStream.Seek(Offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);` because the offsets are relative to the `cmap` table's own offset. Also, drop your font onto https://pomax.github.io/A-binary-parser-generator/test/OpenType/validate.html to get a view into the byte layout.

Comment: Ah, thank you, it definitely is the offset thing that is throwing me off.

Comment: What are you using as reference docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap may be a bit dense, but all the information's there, you just need to be careful to pay close attention to the data types, and any addition notes in paragraphs following the type tables. Also, while SO is useful as a general programming Q&A site, for opentype implementations you'll definitely want to consider posting on https://typedrawers.com (either "too" or "instead"), all the big names in font software hang out there.